# HTML rel="up" attribute?

Tags: html

I'm using mobile template HTML files on a PHPBB forum. 
I tested the html for errors at http://validator.w3.org/ 
The test results showed the following error

Line 24, Column 66: {navlinks.FORUM_NAME}
  Bad value up for attribute rel on element a: The string up is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.

Not having heard back from the author and not finding much on Google search, I'm trying to understrand what rel="up" does, if anything constructive.
Can't find any mention as an official HTML attribute 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp

wondering if it's probably safe to just remove the phrase rel="up"

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/links.html#link-type-up

Comment: @MartyWallace Linking to w3fools without context or an explanation of why w3schools is wrong here is [spammy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104901) and [unhelpful to the OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120635) when his current problem is concerned.

Comment: @millimoose Fair enough.

Answer (score 12):

The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) keeps a list of [link relationships](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) The latest version is from March 21 2013.

> up: Refers to a parent document in a hierarchy of documents.

Unfortunately, despite the fact that this registry was long established, it was decided that HTML5 would not use this registry and would use a [Wiki page](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions) to list the conforming link types instead.

Up, is listed in a rather insane section marked "dropped without prejudice", which nobody seems to know what to do with, or how to get those link types out of.

It's safe to drop it, but some browsers and browser plugins make use of it. For example, I use a Firefox plugin called "Link Widgets" like this to make use of the link type.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Alohci, thanks. Yet I still don't understand why it's safe to drop - especially when this HTML will be read by mobile browsers. You said that some browsers still use it. Is it bad coding to leave it in? I know that W3 validator tools can often be overambitious at pointing out wrong syntax. I'd rather lean towards leaving it in, if it won't affect page rendering in a browser or negatively effect SEO.

Comment: Look at it as a user convenience feature. Google, I believe make use of "next" and "previous", but not the other relative link relations like up. (Otherwise they'd be valid by now). But equally, it's not a feature that can be used by black hats for anything, so there's no value in them punishing you for using it either. It's not bad practice, it benefits me and others like me, so feel free to leave it in. A validator is only a tool to help you, but no-one will really blame you if you want to remove it to satisfy the validator.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/dochead.html

> **REL=Up**
>   When the document forms part of a hierarchy, this link references the immediate parent of the current document.

If this is causing any specific problems or unexpected results, please post your code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. No specific issues. Only an error spit out by W3 validator, as illustrated above.